# Cool retro term typing LS (in lower case) doesnt work, and ghloging doesnt work either

Tags: command-line

Trying to get a cool retro term to work properly but I'm running into an issue where when I type in `ls`, nothing happens like it's supposed to and then when I type in `ghloging` which is supposed to bring up an image generation like on the cool retro term website, nothing happens there either.  Heads up I'm crazy new to Ubuntu terminal and coding in general so any help to make me understand this stuff better would be greatly appreciated.

Version info:

```
    name:      cool-retro-term
    summary:   cool-retro-term is a terminal emulator.`
    publisher: Filippo Scognamiglio (flscogna)
    store-url: https://snapcraft.io/cool-retro-term
    contact:   flscogna@gmail.com
    license:   GPL-3.0+
    description: |
    cool-retro-term is a terminal emulator which mimics the look and
    feel of the old cathode tube screens. It has been designed to be
    eye-candy, customizable, and reasonably lightweight.
    snap-id: 6d6yw8CVhAYys3Z09b4sGSwzXSWR6btg
    channels:
         latest/stable:    1.1.1 2019-03-28 (150) 100MB classic
         latest/candidate: ↑                            
         latest/beta:      ↑                            
         latest/edge:      0.24  2022-03-31 (387) 124MB -
```

Cool retro term website shows [a gif of the system working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvP54.gif), thus uncertain how to get to that stage.